# Redirecting an entire subfolder to a new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a site `https://www.main.com/sub`

I want to move everything with `/sub` in the URL to a new domain `https://www.new.com`.

I used this below in the .htaccess but it only redirected that specific page.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.main\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^sub/(.*) https://www.new.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

I need everything after `/sub` such as `/sub/topic1` , `/sub/topic2` and so on to also redirect to the new domain. As well as anything past that such as `/sub/topic5/product`

I already have redirects on `www.new.com` to take care of any discrepency in URL structure, I just need to get the traffic from `/sub` to `www.new.com`

Comment: `^sub/(.*)` matches subfolder and all files and directories inside it. Your rule is ok and it should work. The problem could be elsewhere or Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: As @starkeen says, clear your cache (or test it in incognito), or restart your web server.

Comment: I have cleared my cache but it is still not working. `/sub` goes to the new domain, but pages like `/sub/catagory/product` still 404. I need that to resolve to `newdomain.com/catagory/product`